# How can I disable "Initialize Java Tooling" on Eclipse startup?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-pde

In our application which is a Eclipse plugin, when Eclipse starts it takes long time and the users are seeing "Initialize Java tooling" message on the left down corner of application. Because our users don't have anything to do with java, I wonder if it is possible to disable Initialize Java tooling.

Another question: What is Initialize Java tooling?

Comment: Why are you bundling the JDT plugins in your RCP application if you don't want them? Perhaps you should look at your [application assembly](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/tutorials/os-ecl-rcpapp/section7.html).

Comment: I think it is because we are using ErrorLog and it is a part of jdt.debug!

Answer (score 28):

Try to terminate eclipse then backup and delete the folder

```
.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.history
```

Restarting eclipse will not hang the Java Tooling process.

Comment: find the .metadata directory in the workspace directory! Worked for me

Comment: This does not disable the Java Tooling Init at startup.

Comment: This didn't disable the Java Tooling Init at startup, but at least the process that didn't show any signs of progress earlier, completed in some time

Comment: This doesn't help. Still hanging. This shouldn't be upvoted as solution.

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me. Needed @max's comment to find the directory.

Comment: Thanks! In my case it was showing "Initializing Spring Tooling". This works for that too.

Comment: Worked for me in Eclipse 2021-12 (4.22) aarch64 macOS.

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 22):

from Command prompt just type

eclipse.exe -clean

Comment: First Move to path where eclipse.exe is available.

Comment: `.\eclipse.exe -clean` from Windows PowerShell.

Comment: This worked for me - note that I also had previously removed the .history folder as per @salvobis answer below.

Answer (score 14):

The java-tooling  implement a Java IDE supporting the development of any Java application, including Eclipse plug-ins. It adds a Java project nature and Java perspective to the Eclipse Workbench as well as a number of views, editors, wizards, builders, and code merging and refactoring tools. The Java-tooling provides  a development environment  to developer.

**how to disable plugin at startup**

you can try disabling the java-tooling while launching the application.I am giving you a snapshot.

[image]

go find perspective as **Window->Preferences->Run&Launching->java Application->** and make debug an run combobox to none value.
Hope this can solve your problem.

In case of **Eclipse Oxygen**, this settings can be found at:

**Eclipse > Preferences > Run/Debug > Launching > Perspectives > Java Application > Eclipse JDT Launcher**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help. But it is not working really. The problem is that I have to disable this via an eclipse prefrences or programatically. In our devlopment eclipse I want to use java tooling but in our product it should be disabled. I looked at the prefrences in our product under Run/Debug -> Perspectives. There is no Java application, there is just Ant but Initialize Java toolins is working anyway!

Answer (score 11):

There will be a folder `.metadata` in your project workspace directory. Just delete the `.log` files in it and restart eclipse.

Answer (score 3):

Just uncheck "Build Automatically" and force quit Eclipse. Then start it again.
Project>Build Automatically - uncheck
-force quit
-start Eclipse

Answer (score 1):

I know kind of late advice but because I have this issue 3 days now and I am very very frustrated....just have a copy of your eclipse IDE "virgin" as much possible to rerun it. And any plugin you want to have just do it on a direct copied version of this "virgin" eclipse. This is the only way to get away with clumsy plugins and staff under the hood that you cannot control.
It's devastating to import the projects all the time from the start or deleting the metadata folders....

Answer (score 0):

Is to remove or rename the .projects folder in .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources in the workspace folder. This doesn’t seem to affect any project and the .project folder will be recreated when Eclipse restarts

Comment: This does not solve the problem. Instead Eclipse will complain about the missing .project folder all the time.