# RAD Hangs up in startup - Initialize Java tooling

Tags: eclipse, ide, rad

I am using Rational Application Developer 7.5.3.When I open my workspace it shows "Initializing Java Tooling" - 1% for long time.It gets hanged up when I try to open any file in my workspace.

I have referred [How can I disable "Initialize Java Tooling" on Eclipse startup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14642447/how-can-i-disable-initialize-java-tooling-while-eclipse-start) but couldn't get my problem resolved.
[image]
Kindly assist.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse's Bugzilla has a few bug reports about the product hanging during "Initializing Java Tooling". These bugs seem to have been resolved. You're using RAD 7.5.x which is based off a *very* old edition of Eclipse, so I wouldn't be surprised if the underlying Eclipse of RAD 7.5.x suffers from those "Initializing Java Tooling" bugs.

I remember encountering many of these "Initializing Java Tooling" hangs in previous versions of RAD, but haven't seen those in quite a while.

You may wish to upgrade to a later RAD version (the latest at the moment is 9.0.1). If that doesn't help, a PMR with IBM would be the way to go.